# [Java game]: how to implement a game board

Tags: java, swing

For an exam we are developing a distribuited game (using Java RMI) with shared global status which is a game board containing the position of all pawns. Now we have to start to implement the board game which would be the one showed in the following picture:
[image]

The problem is that we have no idea about how to begin. Shall we usa Swing? We have really little experience with Swing...just buttons, labels, textarea and little else...
Can you please give us some adivice about what to use and how to start? Is there any specific library? Thank you

Comment: I would say that this could be done in swing, it would be fairly difficult though. You will want to make a background and a panel on top which holds the circle graphics, (and you will want a graphic for each state of the circle, ie occupied etc) and then make each of the graphics a button as well then work it from there.

Comment: i would say that JLabels are also possible

Comment: I don't know exactly what to say more... as I've said we haven't any experience so it's hard for us to understand how to start...

Comment: I guess it depends on if you have the time to invest in learning to work with the answers the other people gave. 
It is very much do-able using the standard Swing components (JLabel/JButton etc.). You can just place the JLabels by using label.setBounds(x,y) to put it anywhere withing the panel :)

Comment: You should design your [Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) first - this will be the shared object that resides in `RMI` shared space. Once that is done you will probably be able to build `View/Controller` objects in any (or even all) of the frameworks you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use JLabels as I also don't have experience with Swing. You can make them clickable pretty easy and same goes for moving them around the screen.

This being said,

Swing would be the way to go, if you want to learn something new, and impress the teacher :)

Because i feel you are looking for more direction, i'll expand a little on how i'd tackle this problem.

- create class boardField extends JLabel (or whatever you wanna call the circles)
- make it have states : empty , occupied
- keep track of the boardFields with an arraylist
- Get board to display in JPanel

add all the stuff i didn't mention :P

Comment: to which i'd like to add, that other answers might be better. But it seems you are looking for an easier way to do it. And since you've worked with this components so far, you should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into an existing Java implementation of OpenGL if you plan to make advanced graphical features such as these, for example [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). This is possible through Swing but it is a lot of work and messing around.

It's a bit of extra learning however it's a good step forward in making an impressive cross-platform game. You'll be able to present it on android and iOS as well which is a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

I would create my own `JComponent` by subclassing it and overriding its `paintComponent` method to draw the board. Like this :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyBoardComponent extends JComponent {
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawOval(50,50,100,100);
  }
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(200,200);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
          f.getContentPane().add(new MyBoardComponent());
          f.pack();
          f.setVisible(true);
        }
      });                       
  }
}
```

Of course, you will now need to design a good model for your board and change the code of `paintComponent` to draw it correctly on screen accordingly to the current state of the game.

I can suggest you to read the "[Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)"

Answer (score 0):

Actually for something like this I'd either use a OpenGL library like libGDX or JavaFX. JavaFX may lead you to a result a little faster compared to going by it using libGDX.

libGDX was already mentioned by Cod in the other answer.
JavaFX is build in in newer Java versions and has better support when it comes to graphical editors and such things.

Comment: ok, thanks for your advice...the problem is we don't know where to start from...even if we decide a library then we are not able to begin the board game :(

Comment: For JavaFX you can start with a Canvas (free placement surface) and some cicles. The scenebuilder that is provided by Oracle should help you get started.